# Xamarin. convert audiofile to mp3 for iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, audio-converter

I have a problem with converting audio file from wav to mp3.
My app records voice and saves audiostream to user_audio_raw.wav.
After that i try to convert this file to mp3 format:

```
var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "user_audio_raw.wav")));

var export = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetLowQuality);

var u = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "user_audio_rec.mp3");

if(File.Exists(u)) {
     File.Delete(u);
}

export.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "user_audio_rec.mp3"));
export.OutputFileType = AVFileType.MpegLayer3;
export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;

export.ExportAsynchronously(() =>
{
     if (export.Error != null)              
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(export.Error.LocalizedDescription);
     else {
         Console.Write("Converted success!");
}
};
```

App crashes when i call export.ExportAsynchronously() with next message:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[AVAssetExportSession setOutputFileType:] Invalid output file type
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181fc9d1c <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181218528 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   AVFoundation                        0x000000018787fcc0 <redacted> + 0
    3   BattleSpeak.Platform                0x00000001012276d0 BattleSpeak.Platform + 13596368
..........................................
```

But when i try convert to mp4 or any another format app works perfect and convert without any problem.
Does anybody know why it can happen?

Comment: I think PresetLowQuality only works with QT files.  You need to pick a preset that works for Audio.

Answer (score 1):

`AVFileType.MpegLayer3` is a ***layer*** type that can be used within an mpeg video container, but you can not use it to *export* to an audio only `.mp3` file.

Note: You can import mp3, but not export, I've never seen an official answer, but most people refer to the mp3 licensing issues...(?)

You can test if the combination of an asset with an `AVFoundation` file type (UTI) and an export preset is a valid combination in order to avoid a native exception via `DetermineCompatibilityOfExportPreset` / `DetermineCompatibilityOfExportPresetAsync`:

```
var ok = await AVAssetExportSession.DetermineCompatibilityOfExportPresetAsync(
    preset,
    asset,
    UTIConstant
);
```

Testing a `.wav` asset against all the available presets and export types, you will see that mp3 is not a supported format. One of the available options is:

```
 AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
```

if `.m4a` format is an option for your app.

I NSLog'd a list of all presets/filetypes against a `wav` asset:

```
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
  True:       QuickTimeMovie : com.apple.quicktime-movie : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
  True:                Mpeg4 : public.mpeg-4 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
  True:             AppleM4V : com.apple.m4v-video : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:             ThreeGpp : public.3gpp : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
  True:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:             AppleM4a : com.apple.m4a-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:      CoreAudioFormat : com.apple.coreaudio-format : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Wave : com.microsoft.waveform-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Aiff : public.aiff-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Aifc : public.aifc-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                  Amr : org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:            ThreeGpp2 : public.3gpp2 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:           MpegLayer3 : public.mp3 : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                SunAU : public.au-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                  AC3 : public.ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:          EnhancedAC3 : public.enhanced-ac3-audio : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Jpeg : public.jpeg : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                  Dng : com.adobe.raw-image : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Heic : public.heic : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Avci : public.avci : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Heif : public.heif : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPreset640x480
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPreset960x540
 False:                 Tiff : public.tiff : AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080
```